# is it possible to replace [ to [[] and ] and ] to []] in sybase

Tags: replace, sybase

I have a string to search. the string is : `[closed]`
Now because of the special meaning of [], i have to replace each [ with [] and ] with [].
this will work fine if only one of them is present in the string to search. if both close and open brackets are present, then its giving issues.
first it will update the string as [[]closed]
then it will replace the ] bracket and result will be like 
`[[[]]closed[]]`.
Is it possible to replace `[closed] to [[]closed[]]`

example : i am searching in a column for data having the pattern [closed].
Now since [ and ] have special meaning in sybase it wont search for exactly [closed]. So inorder to do the search exactly we need to replace [ with [[] and ] with []]. so the string will look like [[]closed[]]. 
Thanks
rinu

Comment: I am not quite understanding the pattern here, if the replacement worked, you wouldn't be able to distinguish `[` and `]` since you replace both with the same, `[]`, can you elaborate what you need here, give some examples?

Comment: have updated the question.hope you got the point

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to do this and why this will make searching possible, if `[` and `]` have special meaning in your search, then won't this just add more of the same problem? In any case, if you can find a "magic value" that is guaranteed never to be present you can do a replace of one of the brackets to that first, and then back afterwards: `Replace(Replace(Replace(input, '[', '§§§'), ']', '[]]'), '§§§', '[[]')` - but again, I'm not sure this actually solves anything for you.

Comment: Also note that your question says to replace `[` with `[]`, but your example replaces `[` with `[[]`, please clean up the question so that it is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the input. since [] has special meaning, if i search for [asd] it will give me a random result. So to avoid this i need to escape the special mean. I found a way to do this without replacing as below.
first replace the open bracket as
select @string = str_replace(@string,'[','|[')
then in the main query where i am searching for add an escape keyword as below
column_name like '%@string%' escape '|'